# Disable clicks outside of element

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a  within my body that contains buttons which are clickable.  I would just like all elements outside of this div to be unclickable.

I tried covering the entire body with my H1 and adding pointer-events: none and a z-index +1 to my div but clicks are still detected outside my div..

I can't do none for the Body pointer-events because that will disable my entire pages..

This is an issue because when it's player 2's turn to go, if player 2 accidentally clicks outside the gameboard then they will put down an X instead of a desired O

```
<body>
  <h1> Tic-Tac-Toe</h1>

<div class="gameboard">
    <button class="tic" id="1" onclick="clicked()"></button>
    <button class="tic" id="2" onclick="clicked()"></button>
    <button class="tic" id="3" onclick="clicked()"></button>
    <button class="tic" id="4" onclick="clicked()"></button>
    <button class="tic" id="5" onclick="clicked()"></button>
    <button class="tic" id="6" onclick="clicked()"></button>
    <button class="tic" id="7" onclick="clicked()"></button>
    <button class="tic" id="8" onclick="clicked()"></button>
    <button class="tic" id="9" onclick="clicked()"></button>
  </div>

  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/app.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: you can put `pointer-events: none;` on `body` & then add `pointer-events: all;` to the only things you want clickable

Comment: `if player 2 accidentally clicks outside the gameboard then they will put down an X instead of a desired O` what's causing this though? Did you add a clickListener to `<body>`? https://jsfiddle.net/khrismuc/woLn8zat/

Comment: Show the JavaScript too. Are you delegating from `body`? if so then delegate from `.gameboard` instead...

Answer (score 2):

You may have an easier time if you use a full-fledged JavaScript `eventListener` instead of just adding the `onclick` attribute to some of your HTML elements.

**Any function you name via the `addEventListener` method automatically gets access to the event** that triggered it (like a `click` event). When you define the function, you just give it a parameter (which can be named anything, but "`event`" is a pretty intuitive choice) -- then inside the function, you access the `event` object as a local variable with that same name.

**The `event` object has a property called `target` that holds the HTML element where the event happened** (in this case, hopefully one of your buttons). Once you know what the user clicked on, you have the power to act accordingly -- like by responding to the click or ignoring it:

```js
document.addEventListener("click", handleTicClick); // Runs the function when a click happens

function handleTicClick(event){
  const whatGotClicked = event.target; // Remembers the HTML element that got clicked
  if(whatGotClicked.classList.contains("tic")){ // Checks a condition related to the element
    console.log(`Hey, somebody clicked on button #${whatGotClicked.id}!`);
  }
  else{
    console.log("Let's just ignore this click");
  }
}
```

```css
button{ margin-bottom: 0.3em; }
```

```html
<h1> Tic-Tac-Toe</h1>
<div class="gameboard">
  <button class="tic" id="1">_</button>
  <button class="tic" id="2">_</button>
  <button class="tic" id="3">_</button>
  <br />
  <button class="tic" id="4">_</button>
  <button class="tic" id="5">_</button>
  <button class="tic" id="6">_</button>
  <br />
  <button class="tic" id="7">_</button>
  <button class="tic" id="8">_</button>
  <button class="tic" id="9">_</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Awesome thank you.  I should have posted my JS as well.  It was in the right direction but needed a touch up

clickCount = 0;
// newButtonValue = '1'
function clicked() {
    var button = document.onclick = clickedTag => {
        newButtonValue = clickedTag.target.id;
        console.log(clickedTag.target.id);
        clickCount += 1;
        if (clickCount % 2 == 0) {
            document.getElementById(newButtonValue).innerText = 'O';
        }
        else {
            document.getElementById(newButtonValue).innerText = 'X';
        }     
}

Comment: Counting clicks is ok to just show Xs and Os (with `clickCount+=1` inside an `if`), but checking the state of gameboard could open up a lot of options to you. A function that just loops through the buttons and pushes their `innerText`s to an Array would give your script access to this state (something as simple as `state = [X,_,_,O,O,X,X,_,O]` Then you might be able to... check the move# (by counting non-"empty" squares), check for gameOver (by finding 3 symbols in a 'row' somewhere, or all boxes full), even build an AI to play the game (by "trying" all the legal moves and rating each result)!

Answer (score 1):

Just add a little bit of JS.

```js
document.addEventListener("click", e => {
  if (!e.target.closest(".gameboard")) return;
  console.log(e.target);
});

function clicked() {
  console.log(1);
}
```

```html
<h1>Tic-Tac-Toe</h1>

<div class="gameboard">
  <button class="tic" id="1" onclick="clicked()"></button>
  <button class="tic" id="2" onclick="clicked()"></button>
  <button class="tic" id="3" onclick="clicked()"></button>
  <button class="tic" id="4" onclick="clicked()"></button>
  <button class="tic" id="5" onclick="clicked()"></button>
  <button class="tic" id="6" onclick="clicked()"></button>
  <button class="tic" id="7" onclick="clicked()"></button>
  <button class="tic" id="8" onclick="clicked()"></button>
  <button class="tic" id="9" onclick="clicked()"></button>
</div>
```